# Amzon Web Services (AWS) - Aggregating DynamoDB Data

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

We have a DynamoDB Database that is storing machine sensor information in the "structure" of :

HashKey: MachineNumber (Number)
SortKey: EntryDate (String)
Columns: SensorType (String), SensorValue (Number)

The sensors generate information almost every 3 seconds and we're looking to measure a (near) real-time KPI to count how many machines in a region were down in the past hour for more than 10 minutes. A region can have close to 10000 machines so iterating through DynamoDB is taking almost 10+ minutes for a response. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: You should look into DynamoDB Streams.  You could perform this type of calculation by ingesting the stream and inserting the results/aggregation into a separate table.  Performing a scan on this smaller aggregated table should give better performance.

Comment: Hi @JaredHatfield, thanks for the input. Streams seems like it's just tracking changes that occur in DynamoDB? How do you process these changes after that --- would I need to create a separate an application web service to handle these or is there something in AWS that I'm  missing?

Comment: Yes, you would write an application to perform the logic required.  In your case some type of aggregation or tracking of specific data.  You can run this application on your own server, but using Lambda you can have Amazon run your code (nodejs or Java) and not have to manage any infrastructure yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Describing the answer as discussed in comments on the question.*

---

Performing a table scan on a very large table is expensive and should be avoided.  DynamoDB Streams provides the ability to process records using your own custom code after they are inserted.  This allows for aggregations or other computations to be performed asynchronously in near real time.  The result can then be written or updated in a separate DynamoDB table.

You can run the code that processes the DynamoDB Stream messages on your own server (example: EC2), but it is likely easier to just utilize Lambda.  Lambda lets you write Java or NodeJS code that will be run on AWS infrastructure that is fully managed so all you need to worry about is the code.